# Permesso di Soggiorno and Moldova citizenship

Tags: passports, italy, mexico, visa-free-entry, moldovan-citizens

Can I travel to Mexico (tourism purposes) with a Permesso di Soggiorno and a biometric passport of Rep. of Moldova citizenship without visa?

Comment: Are you a permanent resident?

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, the Mexican Immigration Department [says that](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/):

> No requerirá visa mexicana el extranjero que presente alguno de los siguientes documentos:
>
> a) Documento que acredite residencia permanente en Canadá, Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte, cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen, así como en los países miembros de la Alianza del Pacífico (Chile, Colombia y Perú).
>
> b) Visa válida y vigente de Canadá, de los Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte o cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen.

or, in English (my unofficial translation):

> A foreigner who presents one of the following documents does not require a Mexican visa:
>
> a) A document that proves permanent residence in Canada, the United States of America, Japan, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, any of the countries that make up the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), or the [Pacific Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Alliance) (Chile, Colombia, and Peru).
>
> b) A valid, in-force visa from Canada, the United States of America, Japan, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, or any of the countries that make up the Schengen Area.

Depending on the type of *permesso di soggiorno* that you have, it may be a permanent residence card (document type "a" above) or a temporary residence card. If it is a temporary residence card, you can not use it to enter Mexico, but in that case you probably also have a valid visa (document type "b" above) for entering Italy, a country in the Schengen Area. Moldovan citizens normally must obtain a visa to visit Mexico, but assuming you have one of these documents, you can use that document to enter Mexico without obtaining a separate Mexican visa.

Comment: This is for **permanent** residence permit holder, and doesn't encompass the case of temporary residence permits

Comment: @Zina This answer is correct only if, as Nicolas Formicella points out, your Permiso di Soggierno shows permanent residence in Italy. You can add an image of your card (after obscuring your name and photo and other ID information) to your question using the "edit" button below your question text, followed by clicking the "moon and mountains" button that appears above the text entry area. Someone here is likely to be able to correctly assess if your card is the card of a permanent resident.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella and DavidSupportsMonica: ah, thanks for the clarification, I misunderstood the different types of _permessos di soggiorno_. I've updated my answer to include another exception to Mexico's visa rules, one or the other of which is probably applicable here.

Comment: @mlc Does *a valid, in-force visa* mean simply what it says, or is there any requirement for the visa to have been used to enter the issuing country at least once in order for it to be accepted for entry to Mexico?