# Can I travel to Mexico with an Italian residence permit and refugee travel document?

Tags: mexico, refugees, italian-residents

I am a Afghani citizen with an Italian residence permit (ASILO) and *documento di viaggio per rifugiati* (refugee travel document). I would like to travel to Mexico over Christmas. I don't have a visa. Will my Italian residence permit allow me to enter Mexico?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permesso di Soggiorno and Moldova citizenship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174932/permesso-di-soggiorno-and-moldova-citizenship)

Comment: @mlc They don't have a passport, they have a refugee travel document

Comment: Thanks .I have residence permit (ASILO)  for 5 years and(refugee travel document

Answer (score 1):

You will require a visa, from [TIMATIC](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/us/timatic) :

> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions
>
> Stateless persons and refugees residing in Italy for a maximum stay of
> 180 days, if their original passport was issued by Andorra, Argentina,
> Australia, Austria, Bahamas, Barbados, Belgium, Belize, Brazil,
> Bulgaria, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, Croatia, Cyprus,
> Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hong Kong
> (SAR China), Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Israel, Italy, Jamaica,
> Japan, Korea (Rep.), Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg,
> Macao (SAR China), Malaysia, Malta, Marshall Isl., Mexico, Micronesia
> (Federated States), Monaco, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Palau,
> Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Russian Fed., San
> Marino, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland,
> Trinidad and Tobago, Turkey, USA, Ukraine, United Arab Emirates,
> United Kingdom or Uruguay.

To get a visa for Mexico, you can find all information for it on [Milan Consulate General](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/milan/index.php/visti) website, with the time to get a visa to be ~10 days